# Jest can't transpile node_modules

Tags: unit-testing, ecmascript-6, babeljs, jestjs

I am having the following error when running Jest

```
SyntaxError: node_modules/my_styleguide/src/components/blocks/SegmentSetting.jsx: Unexpected token (46:10)
  44 |         ) {
  45 |         return (
> 46 |           <p className="SettingDescr">{self.props.description}</p>
     |           ^
  47 |         )
  48 |       }
  49 |     }
```

The node_modules dependency is still in its es6 format. Jest doesn't seem to provide the option to transpile your node_modules, as it does with your actual app. Instead, jest ignores the node_modules folder.

The .bashrc file looks ok to me:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

How do you make Jest transpile your node_modules too? It would be the equivalent of the "--ignore false" flag that we have in mocha.

Comment: Have you installed `babel-jest`?

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Yes. It is transpiling the app fine. It is only the node_modules dependency that seems to ignore

Comment: Have you tried to reset the `transformIgnorePatterns` in the Jest setting. `node_modules` is ignored by default. So set it to  `transformIgnorePatterns: []` maybe helps.

Comment: That would make sense @AndreasKöberle. I am having this error ...
Error: Unknown config option "transformIgnorePatterns" with value "". This is either a typing error or a user mistake and fixing it will remove this message.
I am using double quotes and an empty array [] as a value. I have also tried an empty array with double quotes inside [""]

Comment: seems its new in v17 `npm install jest@17.0.0 --save-dev`

Comment: btw. the best way is to just mock out this dependencies,

Answer (score 2):

I would mark this as *an* answer rather than *the* answer.

I had a similar issue, multiple components in node_modules in ES2015 and in need of transpilation.

I updated `transformIgnorePatterns` to:

`["/node_modules/(?!(our-react-components-.*?\\.js$))"]`

The negative look-ahead for modules in `our-react-components-*` folders mean Jest (and therefore Babel) will find and transpile our shared components.

This was in an ejected Create React App project with Jest 20.0.4.